# htaccess Rewrite for any domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following lines written multiple times to accommodate the multiple domains we use. Would there be a way to write this once so any domain would follow the same rule?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example.com/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example.com/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example.com/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this single block of rule for all the doamins:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+?)::\s/+\1/(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)::/(?!\1/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1/index.php [L]
```